# Session object disappears after manual redirect (node / express - module: mozillia/client-sessions)

Tags: ajax, node.js, session, cookies, express

I have an ajax call hitting a post route which instantiates a session with a cookie using the npm package 'client-sessions'. The response of the post-route is a url to redirect to which the ajax call performs in the done function:

```
.done(function(response){
      console.log(response);
      response = JSON.parse(response);
      if(response["redirect"]){
        window.location.href = response["redirect"];
      }    

  });
```

following this redirect the client-browser makes a get request to the redirect url, and when that happens the request coming in to the server no longer has a session object associated with the request, but their are still cookies (not sure why the cookie doesn't instantiate a req.session object).

I've also asked about it in reddit:
https://www.reddit.com/r/node/comments/3syi8z/clientsessions_mozilla/

The github repo of the session manager I'm using:
https://github.com/mozilla/node-client-sessions

Thanks yall!

EDIT: I've discovered that the size of the session that I'm creating is roughly 11158 bytes - which exceeds the maximum cookie size (4k). I'm sure this plays into what I'm experiencing but I'm not exactly sure how yet. Will update soon.

EDIT2: Oh yeah this definitely screws things up. The cookies properties can't even be properly set. Browser probably just rejects it out right, but not sure where precisely this happens in the full-stack flow of things.

Comment: If perchance anyone else comes across this problem know this:
1. You can use the localStorage object in the browser to save persistent data
2. You can use the sessionStorage object in the browser to save persistent data that will last for the duration that the browser is kept open.
- both of these solutions do not have the 4k byte data-size cap that cookies do